# How do I declare a pointer at a specific memory address in go golang and store a value there

Tags: go, memory, memory-management

So let's say that I absolutely NEED to store a value at a specific memory address of `0xc0000140f0` in go. How would I do this. For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    targetAddress := 0xc0000140f0
    loc := (uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(targetAddress))
    p := unsafe.Pointer(loc)
    var val int = *((*int)(p))
    fmt.Println("Location : ", loc, " Val :", val)
}
```

This results in the following errors:

```
./memory.go:10:33: cannot convert targetAddress (type int) to type unsafe.Pointer
```

Comment: this "works" if one uses `var targetAddress uintptr = 0xc0000140f0`, but I don't know enough about Go to say that it is a good solution.

Comment: The error shows where you are using an int, which is not a type that be converted to an [`unsafe.Pointer`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Pointer). Use a `uintptr` (though this is resulting in undefined behavior, and will fail `go vet` with "possible misuse of unsafe.Pointer")

Comment: jakub - Your comment did the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error says, your type conversion is invalid. From the `unsafe.Pointer` [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer):

> - A pointer value of any type can be converted to a Pointer.
> - A Pointer can be converted to a pointer value of any type.
> - A uintptr can be converted to a Pointer.
> - A Pointer can be converted to a uintptr.

Note that "Pointer" (caps) refers to `unsafe.Pointer`, while "pointer value" refers to regular Go pointers like `*int`

Go has a strict type system, so you need to check the appropriate types for what you're using, and pay attention to type errors.

The correct version of your code, which tries to **load** the value from the given memory address, is this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    loc := uintptr(0xc0000140f0)
    p := unsafe.Pointer(loc)
    var val int = *((*int)(p))
    fmt.Println("Location : ", loc, " Val :", val)
}
```

As the title suggests, you also want to **store** a value, which would look like this:

```
*((*int)(p)) = 1234
```

Now if you want to maintain that pointer to keep using it, you can store it as a regular Go pointer:

```
var pointer *int = (*int)(p)
val := *pointer // load something
*pointer = 456 // store something
```

Of course, the use of `int` here is completely arbitrary. You could use any type, which will determine the meaning of "a value" in this context.